# Are questions on security of embedded systems on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Several years ago I read a paper about some smaller American university that used a (self-developed, IIRC) CAN bus fuzzer on a US middle class car. In the lab / garage they found that they could engage the breaks, even while driving and verified this on a small airfield...

Even after *very* intensive search I can't find that paper or website and would like to ask experts in the field for help.

I'm wondering if such a question would be on topic here, or better placed on one of the more IT relevant SE sites...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We actually have an information security Stack Exchange where this is entirely on topic. We wouldn't detail how to break security controls, but we will be able to answer questions on securing these systems, implications of successful attack, risk profiles etc.

Visit security.stackexchange.com